# Slow preview in the layout/modelling tab

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

So I am very new to blender and I am currently doing the donut tutorial..I am having an issue. When I try to preview the donut in the shading tab it previews it very quickly but when I do the same in the layout tab it loads very slowly. The viewport is set to 32. I have a 1050ti and the render engine is set to Cycles. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The shading tab uses material preview (aka lookdev) mode by default. This is a preview mode designed for fast viewing and uses a render engine more similar to eevee than cycles. You can switch modes from any tab by selecting one of the 4 little circles on the top-right (by default) of the viewport, or by pressing Z over a 3D workspace, and choosing your preview mode from the pie menu that appears.

Comment: Yaa I am pretty sure that I am using cycles..I will upload a video soon.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Sd2IfTR

Comment: Oh, I see. It renders faster in the shading tab because the viewport window is less than half the size. Smaller viewport = less pixels to render = faster render.

Comment: Ohh got it..Thank you very much..Please post your comment as answer so I can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the scene is rendering faster in the Shading Tab is because by default, the 3D  viewport in that tab is less than half the size of the 3D viewport in the Layout tab.

*Very simply put* - The scene renders faster in the shading tab (in your example) because the viewport is smaller, and therefore there are less pixels to render overall.